# Java System.out.println format

Tags: java, println, system.out

I need the system out println to do this format so that the number of whitespaces between the first column and the second column varies based on the content. So the second column is always alligned.

Any way to set the second column to start at fixed position?

```
token: accept                        lexical unit: ACCEPT_KEYWORD
token: a                             lexical unit: IDENTIFIER
token .\’n’                          lexical unit: END_OF_INSTRUCTION
token: perform                       lexical unit: PERFORM_KEYWORD
token: find                          lexical unit: IDENTIFIER
token: until                         lexical unit: UNTIL_KEYWORD
token: b                             lexical unit: IDENTIFIER
token: =                             lexical unit: EQUALS_SIGN
token: 0                             lexical unit: INTEGER
token .\n                            lexical unit: END_OF_INSTRUCTION
```

Comment: Try the use of the `\t` escape when defining the string.

Comment: Have you heard of a search engine called Google? It can often help you with your problems. e.g. http://google.com/search?q=java+string+format

Comment: Or just create a string of blanks that you print between the two columns. The number of blanks in that string can vary depending on the column content's length.

Comment: @LeeMeador Not sure if that would work. Aren't some characters bigger than others?

Comment: @Cruncher Terminals are generally fixed-width.

Comment: @hexafraction in that case, i'd much rather do that than the tabs. The tabs you have to calculate how many to put anyway

Comment: @Cruncher OP said that a fixed number of whitespace chars was required. That sort of assumes fixed width chars to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have buddy:

```
    public class Test {

        public static class Logger {

            private static final int MAX_WHITESPACES = 20;

            public static void s(String token, String lex) {
                String whitespaces = new String(new char[Math.abs(token.length()-MAX_WHITESPACES)]).replace('\0', ' ');;
                String line = String.format("token: %s"+whitespaces+"lexical unit: %s", token, lex);
                System.out.println(line);
            }

        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Logger.s("accept","ACCEPT_KEYWORD");
            Logger.s("a","IDENTIFIER");
            Logger.s(".\\’n’","END_OF_INSTRUCTION");
            Logger.s("perform","PERFORM_KEYWORD");
        }


    }
```

Take note that all your tokens must be < MAX_WHITESPACES

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.format()` to create a formatted line.
[For more information.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

Use a width for the token that's the same for all fields, larger than the max token size, and it will line up.